# Zonal Histogram Output Problems - No values associated with the habitat type

Tags: arcgis-desktop, statistics, zonal-statistics, histogram, arcgis-10.3

I have a outline of some islands (shapefile or raster) and GAP landcover data (raster). I am trying to use Zonal Histogram to create a file with a histogram of the habitat types in each island. Each habitat type has a value that is the field I'm computing the histogram for.

Sounds easy enough, right? Well, ArcGIS 10.3 has problems with the zonal histogram, so I'm also using ArcGIS 9.3 SP1 on a virtual machine.

So here's the problem - the file that ArcGIS creates doesn't include that habitat ID value in the histogram - the rows are just labeled 1-255 sequentially  (I have 115 habitat types). I can't figure out what order they are actually in and I can't make any sense of how to paste them in by hand. There are a number of lines that are just 0's across the board. Deleting the 0 rows does not result in 115 rows.

I've been plugging away at this in both versions of ArcGIS and in R for about two weeks now and keep hitting this wall.

Comment: I figured an answer out myself. Extract by mask, export the attribute table. Do it individually for each island  by selecting the island in the overlay. Or build a working version in modelbuilder.